# ::before vertical line not using 100% height

Tags: themes, css, html

I am making a timeline website for a friend so i need to add a vertical line down the center of the page. The problem is the vertical line only has a height of about 600px instead of using the whole length of the page. I have height set to 100% so I'm really confused why it's not working correctly. Here is the css I am using.

```
    .blog::before{
    content: "";
    background-color: #333;
    width: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid setting height 100% with absolute position will only reserve the height as of the document height not whole page height. To set 100% height as of the whole page, you need to use position fixed. But still afraid that will solve your problem. As positioning with fixed may need some more effort for your layout.